Are brand-name laptop thermal products better than the stock versions?
I am customizing a higher end laptop on HIDEvolution, and it's not clear to me whether having them use brand-name thermal compound/thermal pads instead of the stock versions of each is a good idea.  I definitely do care about the machine staying at a safe temperature, and I'm heavily leaning toward an ASUS ROG Strix, which seems to be ranked as one of the laptops with very good internal cooling.  I'm just not sure if the brands of thermal compound/thermal pads really make a difference or not.  My three options are...

Stock TIM - Thermal Grizzly Conductonaut on CPU + stock thermal compound on GPU + stock thermal pads
Thermal Grizzly Conductonaut on CPU (stock TIM) + Gelid GC Extreme on GPU + Stock thermal pads – installed by HIDevolution
Thermal Grizzly Conductonaut on CPU (stock TIM) + Gelid GC Extreme on GPU + Fujipoly Extreme Thermal Pads on heat sensitive surfaces – installed by HIDevolution

How should I reason through this decision?

Hi! This depends heavily on what the stock TIM is. Some OEMs will advertise what they user, particularly on high-end gaming products; what model are you looking at, and do you know if they say what the stock TIM is?

@JMY1000 I was looking at either the ASUS ROG Strix Scar 17 or the ASUS ROG Strix G17.  They do not say what the stock TIM is.
